# change object.item in setState

Tags: reactjs, setstate

how can i change item in object in getInitialState through setState ?

For example:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {list: [
    {id:'1',
      title: 'The Baby Boss',
      year: '2017',
      quality: 'Blu-ray',
      stars: ['Fred Astaire, ', 'Humphrey Bogart, ', 'Marlon Brando, ', 'Richard Burton, ', 'Charlie Chaplin'],
      Show: false
    },
    {
      id:'2',
      title: 'Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Men Tell No Tales ',
      year: '2016',
      quality: 'HDrip',
      stars: ['John Depp, ', 'Orlando Bloom, ', 'Javier Bardem, ', 'Kaya Scodelario, ', 'Brenton Thwaites'],
      Show: true
    }`
```

More clear. I have created `getInitialState` and than `render`ed it and get on the screen displaying of list objects. I have button and I want click it and change smth in one of the objects. Through items in list i go with 'map' function. As result, I am trying to do smth like this code below:

```
this.setState({
  film.Show: false
})
```

But this way doesn`t work. Which way of getting to my aim is correct ?Thanks for ideas.

Comment: I'm not fully understanding your question. Are you wondering how you could change the state after getInitialState takes place?

Comment: I ve added more details. Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to find your target item and update that:

```
someEventHandler: function(targetId) {
   this.setState({
      list: this.state.list.map(function(film) {
         if (film.id === targetId) {
            film.Show = false;
         }
         return film;
      })
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It work. But I still wanna clarify. When we need to get to some item of the object of one more object, we need to do it with function ?

Comment: Glad to help! Can you provide a more concrete example? I don't understand what you mean by "get to some item of the object of one more object"

Comment: For instance, when we give to our getInitialState object and than one of the items is equal to objects that have other items.  how to get to these items of nested object ?

Comment: @KirillStas I think it might be better to post another question to cover this, but in short, it sounds like perhaps the objects you are iterating over have nested objects or nested collections (arrays)? I'm happy to help more, but without seeing the data and know what the desired output is, I really can't help much.